# Datatypes limitations

Tags: mysql, teradata

Why do we have the limitation on datatypes like Char and varchar etc. but not on Integer ?
Why its designed in such a way ?

Eg:
We can define char(8), but we cannot define Int(8) or integer(8). It would have a max of 11 characters saved for it.

Comment: because the integer are not stored  as "characters" but  . but as binary values ...  for store 256  (0-225) need  a  single byte only  .. not 3 ..  for 256x256  .. 2 bytes ...not 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer have a fixed size of bytes 1-8, depending which kind you have defined.

char has a fixed size of bytes per character so you defined the size of 8 character you get 8 times the size if the character.

As it makes no sense to limit that fixed size if bytes, mysqkl finally kicked it out(in future) and gives now a warning, when you create a integer with a size